# Vue.js. Passing dynamically changing data to child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm making a progress bar, which should receive progress status from method *submitAction*, in which *value* for progress bar constantly updating. Here my code:

**1.Parent component**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <progressbar-component :value="progressState"></progressbar-component>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import ProgressBar from './Progress.vue'
    export default {
        components: {
            'progressbar-component': ProgressBar
        },
        data () {
            return {
                ...
                progress: 0
                ...
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...
            progressState () {
                return this.progress
            }
            ...
        },
        methods: {
            ...
            submitAction: function (event) {
                ...
                let percent = 0
                setInterval(function () {
                    if(someState > 0) {
                        this.progress = percent % 100
                        percent += 10
                    }
                }, 200)
                ...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**2. Child (progress bar) component**

```
<template>
    <div class="progress">
        {{ value }}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'progressbar-component',
    props: {
        value: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Aim:**

Updating *value* in Progress Bar's component, while setInterval is running.

**Problem:**

*value* doesn't update in child component.

**P.S.**

Some parts of initial code are just left out to simplify problem representation:

- this.progress value changes correctly in parent, and I can track it
- through debugger progress bar component also works correctly and
  initial value of *progress* (i.e. 0) passed fine.

Comment: what is some state?? you have if(someState > 0)

Comment: @roliroli it's array length checking, this part works correctly.

Comment: ok do you have imported the progressbar component?

Comment: component works fine, initial data from parent also passed

Comment: It is impossible.You dont have imported the progressbar-component and you dont have register it

Comment: 0 it is not passed.It is its default value

Comment: @roliroli I've just change value's default to another one, but 0 is still here, so it's passed from parent

Comment: Are you sure `progressState` gets updated at the parent component? It seems like the real problem in the condition you have inside the interval. everything else looks ok. It was probably just simplified for the sake of the demonstration, but you don't really need `computed` that just returns data.

Comment: @oniondomes In accordance with [vue.js manual](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) computed components update after updating their dependencies.

Comment: For the callback function in the `setInterval` you are using a normal function. Use an arrow function so that `this` refers to the vue instance and you can acess `this.progress`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this took me some time. Classic mistake. The problem is you don't really change components' `progress` ever:

```
submitAction: function (event) {        
    let percent = 0
    setInterval(function () {
        if(someState > 0) {
            this.progress = percent % 100    // <---- `this` here doesn't refer to the component
            percent += 10
        }
    }, 200)
}
```

to make it work do:

```
submitAction: function (event) {        
    let percent = 0
    setInterval(() => {    // <---- arrow function doesn't have their own `this`, so `this.progress` will refer to the components' value
        if(someState > 0) {
            this.progress = percent % 100 
            percent += 10
        }
    }, 200)
}
```